# sp register points to unexpected address when I change the value of sp and ss

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, offset

I am having problem in a function called `switch_stack` which updates stack segment and stack offset by changing the values of `sp` and `ss`. Suppose I change `sp` to `5555h` and `ss` to `2000h`, I expect `sp` to point at address '5555' and it does so when I move `5555h` to `sp` but when i change the value of `ss` to `2000h`, `sp` starts pointing somewhere else and the data in `[sp]` changes though the value of `sp` remains the same. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: If you are planning to set up new `ss:sp` value, set up `ss` first, then set `sp` in the very next instruction. the `mov ss,..` instruction does temporarily disable interrupts for 1 more instruction execution, so by using it this way you will avoid situation when interrupt will happen with only partially updated `ss:sp` content.

Comment: Are you in real mode? Do you know how segments work? Can you show us the relevant piece of code?

Answer (score 1):

There is no fix.  This is how segment-based addressing works. `ss` and `sp` together form the address of the top of stack, if you change any of the two, the position of the top of stack changes.